# Code returning 90 empty values when pulling hyperlinks from a document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am particularly new to coding, not to mention VBA.  After a week of really cracking down on learning VBA, I've started to get the hang of it.  At the moment, I'm trying to put together a code that will pull the hyperlinks (both addresses and names) out of a word document (eventually word, excel, and power point files), and dump them into the excel file I run the code from.  It also dumps the file path and name at the top of the list.  I can run the code and pull links from 1 file at a time, and the code pops it out after the end of the last filled line.  It will save me endless amounts of time when I have to update links.

```
Sub ExtractWordLinks()
    'the following code gets and sets an open file command bar for word documents
    Dim Filter, Caption, SelectedFile As String
    Dim Finalrow As String
    Filter = "docx Files (*.docx),*.docx, doc Files (*.doc),*.doc, xlsm Files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
    Caption = "Please Select .doc, .docx, .xlsx files only, " & TheUser
    SelectedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filter, , Caption)
    'check if value is blank if it is exit
    Finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If (Trim(SelectedFile) = "") Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'setting up the inital word application object
        Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
        'opening the document that is defined in the open file dialog
        wordapp.documents.Open (SelectedFile)
        'ability to change wether it needs to burn cycles updating the UI
        wordapp.Visible = False
        'declare excel sheet
        Dim xlsSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        'set active sheet
        Set xlsSheet = Application.ActiveSheet
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 1
        'MsgBox (wordapp.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Count)
        For i = 1 To wordapp.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Count
            'puts the title of the document in the formatted cells
            'xlsSheet.Cells(Finalrow + 1, 1).Value = wordapp.ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & wordapp.ActiveDocument.Name
            'formats the file name cell to be a bit easier to discern from the listing.
            Range(Cells(Finalrow + 1, 1), Cells(Finalrow + 1, 2)).Font.Bold = True
            Range(Cells(Finalrow + 1, 1), Cells(Finalrow + 1, 2)).Merge
            'save the links address.
            xlsSheet.Cells(Finalrow + i, 1).Value = wordapp.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks(i).Address
            'save the links display text
            xlsSheet.Cells(Finalrow + i, 2).Value = wordapp.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks(i).TextToDisplay
        Next
        wordapp.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        wordapp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem, is that when I run this code on a simple sample file with 3 or so hyperlinks in it across a single page, it returns everything exactly how I want, with the file path/name at the top and all the links in the page directly below it (address in one column, displayed text in the other).  However, when I run it on one of the files I am writing this code for (a 95+ page .docx file with ~30 links), it prints out the path/file in the formatted section, and then drops 90 (90 every time) blank lines before printing out the path/file a second time, and then all the links in the document.  It does it perfectly, except for the inexplicable second path/file (even there if I comment out the bit I put in) and the 90 blank entries.

Can anyone explain what's going on, or should I try to figure out a way to just bypass the issue by removing my own link code, and including a bit that removes all blank lines?

Comment: There's nothing obvious in your code which would account for 90 extra lines: perhaps there's something in the Word document which you're not seeing? You can always `Debug.Print` the count of hyperlinks to check it's what you think it is. You do have the code which prints the filepath inside the loop which lists the hyperlinks: you should move that outside of the loop.  And currently the first hyperlink listed will overwrite the filepath...

Comment: ...also note that if you want to use Word constants such as `wdDoNotSaveChanges` you'll need to add a reference to the Word library to your Excel VBA Project.

Comment: @user1625335: If you uncomment the line `'MsgBox (wordapp.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Count)` for the 90 page document, what do you get?

Comment: TimWilliams I moved the filepath code outside of the loop and, after some playing around, finally got it to print consistantly and accuratly. After following Siddharth's advice, I figured out the blank rows were from the word document, so I tracked down and added a bit of code that would remove and shift upward any empty rows.

After a great deal of hairpulling, I managed to get everything working!

Siddharth Rout - It just prints how many hyperlinks it finds, which included the weird blank links, so that explains where they were coming from.  

Thanks to both of you!